# create a jar file in the current directory

Tags: java, jar

I am looking to create a jar file in the current directory.

I did this in command line:

```
jar cfe MyApp.jar MyApp MyApp.class
```

Alternatively, i put the following into Mnf.txt:

```
Main-Class: MyApp.class
```

and ran

```
jar cfm MyApp.jar Mnf.txt MyApp.class
```

When i try to run it with

```
java jar MyApp.jar
```

I get the following error in both cases:

```
Error: could not find or  load main class.
```

Mnf.txt & MyApp.class is in the current directory.

There`s no package definition in MyApp. Everything is in the current directory.

I`ve seen [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) among others.

No idea what i`m missing here.

//===================

ADD:

Changing the content of Mnf.txt to:

```
Main-Class: MyApp
```

didn't change anything. i'm getting the same error.

Comment: To create a jar file use `jar` command not `java`

Comment: those are both jar, not java. mistyped here. thanks for the correction.

Comment: What's the output of jar command?

Comment: nothing on command line. it`s creating the jar file,i`m seeing it by jar tf MyApp.jar .

Comment: Use v switch for verbose

Comment: `jar cfev MyApp.jar MyApp MyApp.class` said `added manifest<CR> adding MyApp.class(in=12501)(out=5638)(deflated 54%)`.

Comment: 'jar cfmv ..' said the same thing, + one more line: 'MyApp.class(in=24188)(out=5558)(deflated 77%)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
java -jar MyApp.jar
```

to run the main class in the jar

```
jar cfe MyApp.jar MyApp MyApp.class
java -jar MyApp.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not add ".class" to the name of the class in the manifest.

Java differentiates rather strongly between names of files on disk and class names.

Comment: pls see the part below the line comment. didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

There should be manifest entry: `Main-Class: MyApp` without `.class`

Comment: didn't help. pls see the part below the line comment.